# What is wrong with my kalanchoe blossfeldiana?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-care, succulents, kalanchoe

I bought this lovely girl for my mom last May at Vons, and kept it alive since then. It's been in continual bloom. It gets plenty of shade and sun, and I bring it inside at night and back out in the morning so it doesn't run risk of frost. I believe the huge leaves decaying in the middle are just the old ones and so those don't concern me as much because they've been there since day 1 so they're probably on their way out as it is, but now even these new leaves on the sides are starting to crisp and wither. I don't want it to die :( I use the yellow and green bag of soil and have never fertilized, as this is the only plant I've ever taken care of in my entire life.[image: leaves]
[image: soil][image: whole plant]

Comment: Hey Taylor.   Do you make sure the soil is dry before you water again?   When you say you used the green & yellow bag do you mean MG.   Is it their Cactus & Succulent Mix of just their regular potting soil.    I would love to see a picture of the pot, one of the entire plant and one close-up of the soil.   Where do you live? (general region) This is most likely something to do with the soil so these question are important.   Thanks.

Comment: Yes I make sure the top inch or so is dry. I live in Southern California. I'm not sure what the soil is I think Miracle-Gro. I moved and no longer have the bag. And i would be happy to provide more pics but I could only see how to add a single one. Sorry this is my first post on sxc so I don't know how to add more.

Comment: Repeat the same steps for each additional pic

Comment: If you could add a photo  of the whole plant and its pot, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I have added pictures, hope they help. I just pulled quite a few spent blossoms which is why they are on top of the soil. How do I cut one to propagate another plant?

Comment: Is there a drainage hole in that pot?

Comment: @bamboo yes there is, I think there are rocks at the bottom tho.. my dad was the one who helped me repot it the first time from the grocery store pot and he put rocks and a coffee filter at the bottom. So I did the same thing for this one. Do I need to take them out?

Comment: Not really, just needed to know if there was drainage from the pot. I don't think this is actually Kalanchoe blossfeldiana, but not sure what variety of Kalanchoe it is otherwise, still checking...

Comment: Its definitely the blossfeldiana

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give you the best advice I can with the information given. Check or try the following things do them in order.  Stop once you find the problem.

- Inspect it for insects and mites. All like to feed on new growth.  Mites are hard to see.  Put a piece paper under the plant and gently shake it.  Check the paper for small insect like pest.   -- Use appropriate insect or mite treatment.  Avoid home brews.  Many damage plants.
- Experiment with various light conditions.  Maybe just changing the type or amount of light might alleviate the problem.

9 times of out 10 the problem with a succulent lies in the roots.

- Change the way you water.  Make sure the soil is dry before you water.  There are various techniques to use like - Stick you finger in the soil.  -Do the bamboo chopstick test (insert for 10-20 mins. Pull out and check if the stick is dry or wet).  -Do the weight test. (Give the plant a good soak. lift pot & note the weight in your mind, before you water make sure the pot feels light before you water again.)
- Inspect the roots.  Do this when the soil is fairly dry.  Most succulents will tolerate this abuse with none or very little stress.  If the roots are wet, dark and mushy/soft, then the soil is not draining adequately.  If the roots are firm and white or beige, there is no problem with your soil.

Before you repot the plant,

- take the rocks out of the bottom of the pot.
- If the soil was mushy - Use a cactus & succulent potting mix and add equal parts perlite.  Such as mix 1 cup of C&S mix with 1 cup of perlite.  If you do not have C&S mix use regular potting mix instead.  Make sure you use Potting Mix not Potting Soil or any product with the words soil.
- If the roots were white and firm - mix equal parts perlite to your current potting mix.
- Wait 1 week before you water your plant after repotting.

There is a great chance that one of these steps will fix your problem.